# Add new lines on top in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I'm working with a `TextBlock` and `Inlines` to add new text which contains some information from a HTTP request.

How can I add new text coming from the top instead of a bottom like it works by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `TextBlock` has a name and you modify it from code-behind...

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>
```

You can use [`InsertBefore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textelementcollection-1.insertbefore?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Documents_TextElementCollection_1_InsertBefore__0__0_) with [`FirstInline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.inlinecollection.firstinline?view=netcore-3.1) to add the inline as first element to `Inlines`.

```
MyTextBlock.Inlines.InsertBefore(MyTextBlock.Inlines.FirstInline, new Run("My text to add as first inline."));
```

If you want to put newlines in between the text that you add, use [`LineBreak`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.linebreak?view=netcore-3.1).

```
MyTextBlock.Inlines.InsertBefore(MyTextBlock.Inlines.FirstInline, new LineBreak());
```